# Execution of a subreport in jasper only once

Tags: jasper-reports, subreports

I have a Jasper report which has multiple sub-reports, all of them have separate values. These reports are executed multiple times, is there a configuration I can make so I can execute a specific report only once?

Comment: If you are using detail bands in your main report calling your subreports make sure there is only one row to loop over. Detail bands are repeated for every row in your main dataset. To get more specific help you need to post your relevant code and report data.

Comment: post your jrxml file. It will give better understanding of your question.

Comment: Found the answer for the report

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for the report
It was adding a page break and add a new subreport for the same